# Wrong import error with TS/JS mixing and visual studio code

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a **react native app** with **both JS and TS**.
When I have different configurations according to the OS, I'm creating **two** files.

One for **iOS**, one for **Android**.

[image]

It works pretty well and handle things exactly the way I want, but on **visual studio code** when I import something from the 'firebase' file, **from a typescript file** I get this error

[image]

If I switch the .ts file in question to a .js the errors doesn't appear so it must come from the typescript configuration on Visual Studio, but don't find where..

Edit: **I precise that on the compilation part, it works without error. My app is running well, it's just a visual studio code wrong error.**

Anyone has got a similar problem?

Thank you

Comment: looks like the file you're importing does not exists, import `firebase.ios` or `firebase.android`

Comment: The file exists, it compiles well.

Comment: Aren't you importing a js file from Typescript ?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: @LéoMartin The React Native bundler/builder has a built-in mechanism to pull platform specific override files based on the file extension.  The builder will look for several patterns and drop the js(x)/ts(x) extension and if there is a platform extension, it will drop that too.

Comment: @zero298 thanks for the explanation

Comment: Do you have `allowJs: true` set in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Yes I have. But I repeat it, it compiles, my app is running and works well. It's just wrong visual studio code error

Comment: I don't know that there is a clean fix for this.  I use the same kind of overrides in the project that I work on in Atom and constantly get similar errors about certain overrides not existing or that they aren't modules.